# DFS on undirected graph

Tags: c++, nodes, depth-first-search, undirected-graph

I have an exercise for university where I have to write a DFS algorithm to run on an undirected graph. I also have to make the program sum the values of all nodes show the order in which the nodes were visited.

Here is the given structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    // DATA STRUCTURE NODES

};

int dfs_sum(/* FUNCTION ARGUMENTS */) {
    // DEPTH FIRST SEARCH ALGORITHM
}

void node_init(/* FUNCTION ARGUMENTS */) {
    // INITIALIZATION OF NODE WITH LABEL "value" AND NEIGHBOR "num_adjacent" 
}

void edge_init(/* FUNCTION ARGUMENTS */) {
    // INITIALIZATION OF EDGE BETWEEN TWO NODES
}

void node_delete(/* FUNCTION ARGUMENTS */) {
    // DE-ALLOCATE MEMORY THAT WAS ALLOCATED IN "node_init"
}

void init_nodes(node *nodes) {
    node_init(&nodes[0], 1, 1);
    node_init(&nodes[1], 2, 4);
    node_init(&nodes[2], 3, 1);
    node_init(&nodes[3], 4, 4);
    node_init(&nodes[4], 5, 4);
    node_init(&nodes[5], 6, 2);
    node_init(&nodes[6], 7, 5);
    node_init(&nodes[7], 8, 3);
    node_init(&nodes[8], 9, 2);
    node_init(&nodes[9], 10, 2);
    node_init(&nodes[10], 11, 4);
    node_init(&nodes[11], 12, 2);
    edge_init(&nodes[0], &nodes[1]);
    edge_init(&nodes[1], &nodes[4]);
    edge_init(&nodes[1], &nodes[6]);
    edge_init(&nodes[1], &nodes[7]);
    edge_init(&nodes[2], &nodes[3]);
    edge_init(&nodes[3], &nodes[6]);
    edge_init(&nodes[3], &nodes[7]);
    edge_init(&nodes[3], &nodes[11]);
    edge_init(&nodes[4], &nodes[5]);
    edge_init(&nodes[4], &nodes[8]);
    edge_init(&nodes[4], &nodes[9]);
    edge_init(&nodes[5], &nodes[6]);
    edge_init(&nodes[6], &nodes[9]);
    edge_init(&nodes[6], &nodes[10]);
    edge_init(&nodes[7], &nodes[10]);
    edge_init(&nodes[8], &nodes[10]);
    edge_init(&nodes[10], &nodes[11]);
}

void delete_nodes(node *nodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        node_delete(&nodes[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    node *nodes= new node[12];
    init_nodes(nodes);

    int sum_dfs = dfs_sum(&nodes[0]);
    cout << endl;

    int sum_loop = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        sum_loop += nodes[i].value;
    }

    cout << "sum_dfs = " << sum_dfs << " sum_loop = " << sum_loop << endl;

    delete_nodes(nodes);
    delete [] nodes;
    return 0;

}
```

I do not know how to begin this exercise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with c++ (I think that's what you used) but the implementation is the same anyway so I can give you a pseudo-code of what the algorithm should look like.

```
create a stack where object will be stored
all nodes are not visited when we begin
push source in the stack and mark it as visited
while the stack is not empty;
go to the first adjacent node to source and if it has not been visited
mark as visited and move to its next unvisited node and so on
if at any point you reach a node that cannot visited any other unvisited node
pop the stack until you can visited an unvisited node.
Do this until the stack is empty
```

Below is a simple implementation using an adjacency matrix

```
    void dfs(int adjacency_matrix[][], int source){
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int numNodes = adjacency_matrix[source].length -1;
    boolean [] visited = new boolean[numNodes +1];
    visited[source] = true;
    stack.add(source);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        int current = stack.peek(); // don't remove the element but get it
        System.out.println("Current node being visited is "+current);
        for(int x = 0; x <= numNodes; x++){
            if(adjacency_matrix[current][x] == 1 && visited[x] == false){
                visited[x] = true;
                stack.push(x);
                break;
            }else if(x == numNodes){
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test with a graph like this

```
        0 --- 1-------5----6--8
        | \    \      |   /  /
        |  \    \     |  /  /
        |   \    \    | /  /
        2    3----4---7---9

            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
          ---------------------
        0 | 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
        1 | 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
        2 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        3 | 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
        4 | 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
        5 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
        6 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
        7 | 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
        8 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
        9 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
          ---------------------
```